# How to create stop/start java application like tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

How can i create a java application that can start/stop like tomcat.
It must run 24/24.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your application as a daemon, [Apache Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/daemon) is exactly what you're looking for. It supports both Unix and Win32, and the codebase is originated from Tomcat actually. I have no experience with it myself though.